# How to save 2D numpy array column wise instead of row wise in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I have this array:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[7,8,9]]
```

I tried to use pandas.to_csv but it gives me

```
1 2 3
4 5 nan
7 8 9
```

but I want

```
1 4 7
2 5 8 
3 nan 9
```

Comment: You can use `arr.T` where `arr` is the name of your array.

Comment: Well my array is dynamic, it is not of something like 3 x 3 like first row has 3 elements, second row has 7 elements and so on...

Comment: It'd be much easier to help you if you'd give us test input and desired output. As a quick guess I'd say `df.transpose().to_csv()` should be enough

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the question is about dealing with rows of varying lengths

Answer (score 0):

I would first ensure all rows have the same length:

```
a = [[], [1], [1,2], [1,2,3]]
max_row_length = max([len(r) for r in a])
a = [r + [None]*(max_row_length - len(r)) for r in a]
```

and then I would use numpy:

```
np.array(a).T
```